# Canvas clip() not being reset?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, clip

I am making a bit of an animation where I try to combine 3 images behind and inside each other, and I am partly successful with the `clip()` method.

```
        else if(curpage==103)
        {
            ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
            rot = 0;
            y = 1440;
            a = 0.001;
        }
        else if(curpage==104)
        {
            ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
            rot = 0.6;
            y = 840;
            a = -0.001;
        }

...

var dreamfades = function()
{

    ...

        else if(curpage==103)
        {
            ctx.drawImage(img1,0,0);
            ctx.save();
            ctx.translate(1280,y);
            ctx.rotate(rot);
            ctx.rect(-1600,-465,1600,800);
            ctx.clip();
            ctx.rotate(-rot);
            ctx.drawImage(img3,-1280,-y);
            ctx.rotate(rot);
            ctx.drawImage(img2,-1280,-465);
            ctx.restore();
            if(rot<0.3)
                a+=0.0001;
            else if(rot>0.6)
                a=0;
            else
                a-=0.0001;
            if(rot<0.6)
            {
                rot+=a;
                y-=(a*1000);
            }
        }
        else if(curpage==104)
        {
            ctx.fillRect(0,0,1280,720);
            ctx.save();
            ctx.translate(1280,y);
            ctx.rotate(rot);
            ctx.rect(-1600,-465,1600,800);
            ctx.clip();
            ctx.rotate(-rot);
            ctx.drawImage(img3,-1280,-y);
            ctx.rotate(rot);
            ctx.drawImage(img2,-1280,-465);
            ctx.restore();
            if(rot>0.0)
            {
                a-=0.001;
                rot+=a;
                y-=(a*1000);
            }
        }

        requestAnimationFrame(dreamfades)
}
```

- `img1` is a background image.
- `img2` is an image of a knife where the blade is semi-transparent
- `img3` is an image of the victim that is to be "reflected" in the knife

When the user comes to `curpage==103` it all works as it should: `img1` shows, then the knife slides in wiping away `img1`, and `img3` is shown in the blade only. But when the user comes to `curpage==104`, the knife drops but `img3` is now drawn in the whole canvas rather than the `fillRect()`. If the user comes back to `curpage==103`, `img3` is the background instead of `img1`. If the user goes to another `curpage` and then comes back to `curpage==103`, `img3` is still the background unless one refreshes the page.

I have a feeling that the `clip()` is being persistent in some way, but I do not know how to "unclip()" it. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Add `ctx.beginPath()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/beginPath above the line that define the clip rect `ctx.rect(-1600,-465,1600,800);` it will remove the old path and start a new one

Comment: Ah, thanks. That is what was missing!